# How can I send messages from 1 device to another (both on different internets)

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on a very simple messaging application and can't seem to find an understandable technique to send strings from 1 internet connection to another. I am currently using python sockets to do this.

server:

```py
#server
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.56.1", 5034))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt,adr=s.accept()
    clt.send(bytes(f"sent from {adr}", "utf-8"))
```

client:

```
#client
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 5034))
while True:
    msg=s.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode())
```

Comment: As this stands do you not require 

      s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 5034))

to be

s.connect("192.168.56.1", 5034)

otherwise your client is just listening to itself

Answer (score 0):

To make that happen u have two choices :

-Both devices should be on same internet and same router (better for the development phase)

-The socket server should be deployed online (heroku - netlify ... ) where u have to grab the url/ip and put it in socket connection in the client side

PS: use python-socketio its a better option and very easy to start with

Comment: so will my code work if both of them are on the same internet connection?

Comment: Yes, u just have to put the ipv4 of the socketServer device and then the port e.g.( 192.168.1.105:3000). Here you are opening socket server on ip 192.168.1.105 and on port 3000 . PS: Both devices must be connected to the same router also dont specify the ip in the server side , let it be localhost by default

Comment: Can you help me with how I'm supposed to implement socketio into my code?

Comment: Yeah sure no problem